# How to calculate the MSE for altered data

Tags: machine-learning, standard-error, mse

I am working on a simulation study on income. To make things simpler and since I will not do any further analysis with low & high incomes, I set all citizens with annual income less than $\$10,000$ as $\$10,000$ and all citizens with annual income more than $\$10,000,000$ as $\$10,000,000$.
For example, if citizen Johnny has annual income $\$9,999$, he will be set to have an annual income of $\$10,000$.

Then, I train a neural net with this altered data and the output of this neural net will be the prediction of the annual income.

As a result, I have the altered dataset (True Annual Income) and the prediction dataset (Predicted Annual Income).

Q. When I calculate the MSE, should I also include the altered data? like should I also calculate the MSE of Johnny?

Comment: is the $\hat{y}_n$ = Predicted Annual Income an estimation of  $y_n=$ True Annual Income? the mse $\frac{1}{N} \sum_n (y_n - \hat{y}_n)^2$ should then include all terms $n$, that is the altered $n$ as well. 

Concerning the methodology, I dont know if [censoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censoring_(statistics)) makes the analysis easier if you have the data. An even more simple solution would be to omit the citizens below and above your thresholds.

Comment: @hakanc thanks!